# What are some well known websites that do not require multiple character sets in passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-policy, websites

NIST guidelines discourage password policies that require multiple character sets.

> Verifiers SHOULD NOT impose other composition rules (e.g., requiring mixtures of different character types or prohibiting consecutively repeated characters) for memorized secrets.

<sub>It also [explains why](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#appA).</sub>

I'm currently lobbying within my company, which is primarily a B2B, to adhere to this guidance but experiencing pushback based on the *[argumentum ad populum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum)* that it is "industry standard".

Just judging from memory I can recall that several websites have required multiple character sets, but right now the only ones I can find are Microsoft and StackOverflow .

What are some major websites that I can cite as examples that adhere to the above NIST guideline of *not requiring multiple character sets*?

Comment: As this question will not age well, this has been closed. Questions asking for lists are off-topic, too.

Answer (score 2):

These websites don't require multiple character sets in passwords:

- [Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32040?hl=en) - Includes YouTube and others
- [Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en)
- Facebook
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Password_strength_requirements#Requirements)
- Amazon
- Reddit
- Yahoo
- Twitter
- Instagram

Unfortunately, this list is sparse when it comes to B2B websites which may be more convincing to your B2B peers. If any readers are aware of big B2B website password policies, please add them to this list. This answer is a Community Wiki.

<sub>When possible I have linked to the password policy. When I can't find an explicit password policy, I personally verified their adherence to NIST by creating an account with the all-lowercase password.</sub>

<sub>Interestingly, although many sites do not publish their password policy, they almost universally publish password guidance *recommending* the smart use of multiple character sets, as doing this intelligently is sound password security and in line with NIST guidelines.</sub>